Tales of Tomorrow "Many Happy Returns"
I recently watched the Tales of Tomorrow episode "Many Happy Returns" from October 24, 1952.
The credits say story by Raymond Z. Gallun, teleplay by David Karp.   Did Gallun come up with an original story for the episode, or did Karp adapt a previously published story by Gallun?  I didn't find a story with that title by Gallun, but the title could have been changed.
If there was a previously published story by Gallun as the basis of the episode, what was its title and when was it published?
The illustration of the Moon person looked familiar.  Does anyone know where it was from?

Can you include a picture of the moon person?


Both mad scientists and aliens get a nod in “Many Happy Returns” (10-24-52), with a teleplay that Untouchables scripter David Karp adapted from a story called "Stepson of Space" (Astonishing Stories, October 1940) by Science Fiction Quarterly contributor Raymond Z. Gallun that some erroneous reports claim Astonishing Stories editor Frederik Pohl worked on. It features yet another precocious kid, this one a scientific tinkerer whose weird electronic inventions enable him to communicate with a big-headed alien right out of a future Outer Limits workshop.
Tales Of Tomorrow: The Inside Story of TV's 1st Sci-Fi Anthology


The original story is available at the Internet Archive. A story on the same theme as the much more famous "Zero Hour" by Ray Bradbury.
